# Allow UnhandledException event handler to run when debugging using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, unhandled-exception

I have a WinForms application that uses Application.UnhandledException to display a dialog to prompt user to report the error. When the application is published and run on its own, it works fine (apart from the obvious problem that there is an unhandled exception floating around).

To test changes to it, I've been trying just throwing an exception on clicking a button. Unfortunately, the debugger gets in the way. It will break at the exception (which is not a problem in other cases because I want to know something is wrong) and not let me continue into the UnhandledException handler, instead telling me that the exception is unhandled every time I click the continue button. I've tried disabling breaking on any exception, specific types of exception and the Just My Code option in the Options screens to no avail.

Is there any way of disabling this behaviour?

Repro code below, as requested. It's from a bog-standard, common-or-garden WinForms app with a single button (ThrowButton) on the startup form. Application Framework is enabled by default on creating the project.

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ThrowButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ThrowButton.Click
        Throw New Exception
    End Sub
End Class
```

ApplicationEvents.vb

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            MsgBox("Application event")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I've also put a copy of the solution up on Drive, in case that would be helpful. I scanned it before uploading it, but obviously can't vouch for what happens to it after that.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6VJrYK_X0-QklFWWYtSDBPblU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Visual Studio always says that it's an unhandled exception, even on first chance exceptions. If you read further, it also says "If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: @HansPassant Added example code

Comment: @ThomasWeller I can't see anything about safely continuing. I can't post pictures yet, but [this](http://i.imgur.com/Z02eWf2.png) is the message I get in Studio.

Comment: I was thinking about [this dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/msjES.png), which says "unhandled" but still allows continuing safely.

Comment: Ah. I've never got that one.

Comment: I could reproduce the behavior in VS 2013 Pro Update 4. I think it's just normal for VB.NET to always behave a little more "user friendly". C# behaves more like it should be :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was given for C# code, before OP prepared VB.NET code for download. May it still be useful for someone. If you disagree, flag it as not-an-answer.*

The C# behavior follows the [MSDN steps for exception dispatching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which says in step 3:

> ... but the process is being debugged, the system notifies the debugger a second time.

Considering code like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    throw  new Exception("Help! I am unhandled!");
}

private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught unhandled exception.");
    Console.WriteLine(e.IsTerminating ? "Terminating" : "Not terminating");
}
```

I'd say the behavior of Visual Studio is expected.

1. The unhandled exception handler is executed (which you can verify by looking at the console output)
2. The process is going to terminate, because you can't set the exception as handled in the handler
3. Before the process terminates, the debugger jumps in

The same happens not only in Visual Studio but in WinDbg (running the same executable):

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 750bc42d (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000058)
   ExceptionCode: e0434352 (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 5
   Parameter[0]: 80131500
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
   Parameter[2]: 00000000
   Parameter[3]: 00000000
   Parameter[4]: 713e0000

0:000> !pe
Exception object: 02573148
Exception type:   System.Exception
Message:          Help! I am unhandled!
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    0038F0DC 001D04B4 UnhandledExceptionHandler!UnhandledExceptionHandler.Program.Main(System.String[])+0x6c

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131500
```

Where the exception flags tell us that this is a second chance exception.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm quite happy to keep this around. I use both C# and VB, and may well run into this again in the future.